# Magento Sending Transactional Emails To Previous Customers

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, transactional-mail, ce-1.9.1.0

I have a very strange issue happening at the moment on one of my Magento sites (CE 1.9.1.0).

When an order is placed the transactional email is being sent to the customer correctly BUT is also being sent to the previous customers. The number of recipients of the email is growing with each sale (as in from a certain point every customer from that point is being added to the email recipients).

Can't find any info about this issue anywhere.