# Magento 1.9.1 Email Queue - Order Email Being Sent to Numerous Customers

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, order-email, order-confirmation

I am having issues with the order emails.  This is not the typical issue with emails not sending.  I have a cron job set up properly and all order emails are properly being sent to customers.

BUT... I noticed that one order confirmation email was sent to **3 customers** today.

The issue will not be detected if you have confirmed shipment on your prior orders before getting a new order.  However, when a new customer (Customer A) places an order when there are currently pending/processing orders (Customer B, Customer C), the order confirmation email for Customer A is sent to Customers A, B and C.  Since then I have tested numerous times and found that this issue always occurs.

Anytime there are a couple orders processing, a new order confirmation will be sent to the correct customer and old customers as well.

This is problematic since the email automatically sends customer's personal info (email, address, phone number, etc) to other people.  If you have not noticed this but are using `Magento 1.9.1`, I suggest running multiple test orders using different email addresses and leave them all as processing.

See if the later order results in a confirmation email being sent to all of the various email addresses you used for the test purchase.

All I can find is [this Stack exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72755/magento-order-confirmation-is-sent-to-all-customers) but it has not worked for me

Comment: I'd posted a similar question to this here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69940/magento-sending-transactional-emails-to-previous-customers

Strangely enough the issue just stopped. I couldn't trace where or why it happened but cleared all caches and sessions manually and updated to 1.9.2.0 and the problem went. Not a direct solution so I won't add as an answer but worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

This issue could be related to the new Magento Email Queue system, that leaves orphan records on the Recipients table.

If this is your issue, I've sent a fix on this post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/87299/23057